# How to hide webform Results tab in webform?

Tags: 7, webforms

On my Drupal 7  how hide [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) Results tab?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can hide webform Results tab by restricting user's permission access e.g. uncheck the following checkboxes in permission section :

```
1. view all webform results.
2. view own webform results.
```

Comment: hi Astha chauhan:
Thank you for your suggestion
I have set the following
1. View all webform results.
2. View own webform results.
I want to hide webform Results tab webform page i.stack.imgur.com/VZ4Yx.png

Comment: After unchecking these checkboxes per role basis, result tab will get hide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tab tamer](https://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module to hide the tab from webform.

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy re-ordering,
>   hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs. You can also rename tab
>   labels.
>
> Tab Tamer makes use of Drupal's drag ordering, but degrades gracefully
>   when javascript is disabled.

Comment: I have used the tab tamer
But tab tamer cause the user to see the form of authority is limited

Comment: Do you want to hide this per user role? Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: hi Jayendra Kainthola:
Use tabtamer module, it can only be set NODE /% / WEBFORM-RESULTS tab of the settings in the other to Enabled, Hidden, Disabled.
I want to hide webform Results tab webform page
http://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ4Yx.png